# I am driving a LT3092 current source with a variable voltage - to get a variable DC current, but the output needs to float 0 to 1.5V above ground

Tags: amplifier, driver, output, floating

What type of buffer amplifier would work - either discrete opamps or a differential output opamp?  The output voltage would ideally vary up to 12VDC.  The variable current source has a variable load impedance, but the supplied current has to be precise.  DC only - very low bandwidth needed.

Answer (score 0):

The LT3092 is an Analog Devices, "2-terminal" programmable current source.  It can accept a voltage range from 1.2V to 40V, and provides a current of up to 200mA.  The "load" current is sensed over an external resistor Rout, and controlled to match the voltage drop over a second resistor Rset which carries precisely 10uA.

[image: Example circuit from the Analog Devices datasheet linked above]

*(Diagram and equations from the Analog Devices datasheet for the [LT3092](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3092.pdf).)*

The output current is entirely controlled by the values of Rset and Rout.

By design, variation in the input voltage, to the first order, has no impact on the output current.

Similarly, for a given Iset, the voltage at the load side of the Rout resistor is entirely determined by the impedance of the load.

If for the target current, the load impedance variation yields a voltage of 0 to 1.5V above ground, then that is what will be present at the output pin.  There is no need to alter the supply voltage to control the load voltage.  This happens automatically as part of the operation of the current source.

Comment: OK, thanks, great start.  My problem is that my load impedance can vary, and is tied to ground, so the load voltage can vary from 0 to 1.5V. I am looking for a way to vary the voltage across Rset to vary the current from 0.5 to 55 mA. A single-ended opamp would not work because the varying load voltage would affect the Vset voltage if the opamp is single-ended and grounded. I could tie the ground pin of the opamp to the bottom of Rset, but then the opamp supply current would create an error. This is an industrial instrument application.